# How to check if a specific string is in a variable that byte-variable

Tags: python, string, casting

I have a variable that is received on a socket in *byte* form and I need to check whether a specific string is contained.

For instance:

```
>>> a="foo\r\nbar"
>>> print(str(a.find("\r\n")))
3
```

This works fine, but if the first variable `a` is casted as byte it won't work anymore.

```
>>> a=b"foo\r\nbar"
>>> print(str(a.find("\r\n")))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

It doesn't work either if I cast the variable `a` as a string again.

```
>>> print(str(str(a).find("\r\n")))
-1
```

How can I check for `\r\n` in a byte variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> a = b"foo\r\nbar"
>>> print(a.find(b"\r\n"))
3
```

or you can decode the string as TheGirrafish said

Answer (score 1):

You have to [decode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) your bytes object into a string since casting it won't work.
Try the following code:

```
>>> a=b"foo\r\nbar"
>>> print(a.decode("utf-8").find("\r\n"))
3
```

Your varibale `a` is encoded which is why it can't be compared with a unicode string like `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

Search for a byte string too (as the error suggests!):

```
>>> a=b"foo\r\nbar"
>>> print(str(a.find(b"\r\n")))
3
```

Answer (score 0):

To search and find if a specific string/word is present in a bytes type variable

```
>>> a = b'foo\r\nbar'
>>> print(type(a))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> found = True if b'foo' in a else False
>>> print(found)
True
>>> a = b'\r\nbar'
>>> found = True if b'foo' in a else False
>>> print(found)
False
```